# Are the object models represented by the object diagrams in the semantics of the class diagram?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I've been asked if the following object diagrams in the semantics of the class diagram.

As far as I can tell, I think the answer is yes, though I'm worried I'm missing something.

I don't see a problem with Dana managing herself. It seems consistent with the class diagram.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. To avoid real world confusion the model author should have either added a constraints to forbid such a self-management or chosen a different model approach which does not allow such a construct in first place (depends on a couple of factors and can not be decided here). However, the object model is consistent with the class model.